# Do timers continue if function didn't finish

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services, timelapse

I'm currently creating a Windows Service which makes use of a timer interval. This timer repeats every second, but it could take longer than one second to finish `Elapsed` event of the timer, which is created as following:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Enabled = true;
timer.Interval = 1000; // 1 second
timer.Elapsed += myFunction;
```

Now the simple question: Does this timer continue even though it didn't finished the `Elapsed` event yet, or does the timer wait and continue when the `Elapsed` event finished?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class has an `AutoReset` Property.

If set to `false`, the timer will only run once allowing you to start it again when you function finishes.

If you set it to `true`, the timer will not stop and run your function every second unless an exception pops up.

By default, this property [is set to `true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does

> If the SynchronizingObject property is null, the Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread. If processing of the Elapsed event lasts longer than Interval, the event might be raised again on another ThreadPool thread. In this situation, the event handler should be reentrant.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)